# Does useState hooks effects performance?

Tags: performance, react-native

newbie here. I wanted to know that if I use more than 5 useState hook in my react-native app, does it effects my application performance in a bad way?

Comment: i have been using much more useState hooks, i dont think it affects the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in react, all updates will make a re-render to your app so the fast question is yes.

You need to think about what are you doing for example if you have 2 components to show/hide

This will re-render 2 times

```
[showA, setShowA] = useState(false);
[showB, setShowB] = useState(false);

onClick = () => {
  setShowA(true)
  setShowB(true)
}
```

This will re-render 1 time

```
[showState, setShowState] = useState({showA: false, showB: false});

onClick = () => {
  setShowState((prevState) => {...prevState, showA:true, showB:true})
}
```

Comment: What if we had multiple onClick() function?

Comment: what you mean?.

Comment: Assume the page has 4 buttons and on each button, the click function is called which will change the state. So should I use the different useState for each button or use a single useState for all button.

Comment: it depends if in each button for example you will call 3 setState(individually) it will re-render 3 times instead of 1. If you can handle in one its better, in RN I think is notory because in web react it is so faster but in RN can have a huge impact.